# Row grouping and checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox, datatables

I have a table powered by jQuery DataTables with checkbox in the first column to edit the row data. And I have a time column with duplicate values so I kept the row grouping on that time column.

Now I only need to show one checkbox for grouped row data. For the grouped time data I want to show only first checkbox to edit.

[image]

Comment: You should provide some code snippets, and try to be more specific what exactly is your problem.

Answer (score 3):

#### SOLUTION

Row grouping could be done with [RowsGroup](https://github.com/ashl1/datatables-rowsgroup) plugin for jQuery DataTables. Checkboxes could be implemented with [Checkboxes](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) plugin for jQuery DataTables.

I was able to combine the two using the code below.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   'ajax': 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1us28',
   'rowsGroup': [0,3],
   'columnDefs': [
      {
         'targets': 0,
         'data': 3,
         'checkboxes': {
            'selectRow': false
         }
      }
   ]
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/4k0ddvL7/) for code and demonstration.

#### HIGHLIGHTS

- Row selection is disabled with `'selectRow': false` as it doesn't behave as expected with row grouping.
- Checkboxes use data for the fourth column `'data': 3`.

#### LINKS

- [jQuery DataTables: Row grouping and checkboxes](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-row-grouping-and-checkboxes/)
- [jQuery DataTables: ROWSPAN in table body TBODY](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-rowspan-in-table-body-tbody/)
- [jQuery DataTables: Checkboxes](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-row-selection-using-checkboxes-and-select-extension)

Comment: Hi, Rowgrouping is working but i am getting sorting on the checkbox column .I tired to remove it but because of row grouping it is not working. Can you please help me on that.

Comment: @VijayaSaladi, that's because RowsGroup plugin enforces sorting on grouped columns. Since you need to show 1 checkbox for grouped data, RowsGroup adds sorting arrow to the header with the checkbox.

Comment: why that sorting on the grouping column is not working.As I specified I want to apply the sort on the time column in my datatable.But it not not working.

Comment: @dw, inability to sort by grouped columns and the column containing checkboxes is the current limitation of both plug-ins.